# Wordpress or plugin need tomcat?

Tags: server

I have a managed VPS. It's a CentOS 6.4 + Apache 2.2 + Nginx admin 4.4. When I'm running **top** process in SSH, I can see there's a tomcat process (uses 1.9% RAM). This VPS has only wordpress sites. I want to know Wordpress or its plugin need the tomcat to run? How do I check if a plugin need tomcat?

```
 PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
24085 tomcat     20   0  657m  50m 8728 S  0.0  2.0   0:02.57 jsvc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress does not need [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

All WordPress needs is...

> To run WordPress your host just needs a couple of things:
>
> - PHP version 5.2.4 or greater
> - MySQL version 5.0 or greater
>
> http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Plus adequate RAM-- 32MB for a single site, 64MB for Multisite. Many hosts these days provide much, much more than that by default.

I don't know if there are plugins (or themes) that do, but certainly you can check the Docs for *your* plugins and find out if any of those need it.

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum. I uninstalled tomcat few hours ago, looks like no issue.